# Can I refer to a property in the current Select's object?

Tags: c#, linq

If I have a collection of Person objects, each of whom will have purchases and referrals, what I would really like to do is the following...

```
Peoples.Select(p => new {
  p.ID,
  p.Name,
  Bought = p.Purchases.Sum(pu => pu.Quantity),
  Referred = p.Referrals.Sum(r => r.Quantity),
  Total = this.Bought + this.Referred
})
```

I realise that the last line is incorrect, but I was wondering if there is a neat way of doing this, other than having to loop through the whole collection again and set the Total?

I know I could do the following...

```
  Bought = p.Purchases.Sum(pu => pu.Quantity),
  Referred = p.Referrals.Sum(r => r.Quantity),
  Total = p.Purchases.Sum(pu => pu.Quantity) + p.Referrals.Sum(r => r.Quantity)
```

...but I don't want to, as with a large collection or a more complex calculation, this could slow down the query too much.

Comment: @juharr, your second statement is actually an answer ... post it as answer else am doing so Justin... :)

Comment: Offtopic, but a general remark. Try to keep your code understandable. `Peoples` is correct English when you actually refer to, for instance, the German people and the French people. If you have a _person_ class, the plural is _persons_ or, if you like _people_, but not _peoples_.

Comment: @oerkelens Hee hee, that was Linq2Entities being silly. The table is named People, and it named the entity set Peoples. The code shown was from an ad-hoc query in LinqPad, so it had the default name. The entity set in the real model is named People, and the individual entity named Person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach by introducing a class with calculated getter

```
public class PersonTotal
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Bought { get; set; }
    public int Referred { get; set; }
    public int Total => Bougth + Referred; 
}
```

Then use it in the `Select`

```
var person = Peoples.Select(person => new PersonTotal
                            {
                                Id = person.ID,
                                Name = person.Name,
                                Bought = person.Purchases.Sum(p => pu.Quantity),
                                Referred = person.Referrals.Sum(r => r.Quantity)
                            });
```

Comment: Or even simpler `public int Total => Bougth + Referred; `

Comment: Duh, this is so simple, I could kick myself for not thinking of it! I am using a class, the code I showed was just an ad-hoc LinqPad query, so I can do this without problem. I'll mark this as the answer as it's the simplest approach, but all the answers were good.

Comment: This code is the most inefficient of the solutions presented, each time you call the property it will be computed. Of course this is just a sum, but if there are hundreds of thousands of records to examinate and they're accessed more than once the performance impact can be huge.

Answer (score 4):

If you switch to query syntax you can use `let`

```
var results = from p in People
              let bought = p.Purchases.Sum(pu => pu.Quantity)
              let referred = p.Referrals.Sum(r => r.Quantity)
              select new {
                  p.ID,
                  p.Name,
                  Bought = bought,
                  Referred = referred,
                  Total = bought + referred
              };
```

Comment: You should be able to use `let` for the total as well. ie: `let total = bought + referred`

Comment: People tends to forget the linq query syntax and for some cases is more powerful than lambdas. +1

Comment: @Gusman - queries will be "translated" to methods with lambdas anyway

Comment: @Fabio And? You can argue that C# will be converted at the end to ASM instructions and not for that reason means C# is not more powerful for certain applications...

Comment: As I always use method syntax, I forget that there are tricks like this you can do with fluent syntax (although @RicoKahler's answer does pretty much the same). Thanks for the reminder. I marked Fabio's reply as the answer as it was simpler, but this is also great, thanks

Comment: @Gusman - my point was - that when you write code with functions and then jump to read/write Linq query - you need to "switch" yourself in other syntax flow.

Comment: @Fabio Like when you program functions and database queries on nearly 99.999% of programs today...

Comment: @Fabio which at the end force you to write SQL queries when they don't allow you to do what you want... There's no single program today written with one explicit syntax, on every single prorgam you must mix different syntaxes, for SQL, for UI, for regular expressions etc etc, so if you can't handle that "switch" of syntax then you have a big problem...

Comment: And of course, today are more used micro-orm's than full orms.

Comment: But you can minimize it

Comment: @Fabio and what's the point of minimizing it? Usually when you try to change one syntax to other you do more inefficient code. Keep each part with it's dessignated syntax and don't try to mess up "simulating" things just because you don't understand those, instead of avoiding the problem solve it, learn the new syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a lambda that returns the first expression you could add more braces and return the new object. Now you can use the scope of this function to assign `bought` and `referred` to to variables and then reuse them.

```
Peoples.Select(p => {
  var bought = p.Purchases.Sum(pu => pu.Quantity);
  var referred = p.Referrals.Sum(r => r.Quantity);
  return new {
    p.ID,
    p.Name,
    Bought = bought,
    Referred = referred,
    Total = bought + referred
  };
})
```

Comment: Obvious when you see it!  I marked Fabio's reply as the answer as it was simpler, but this is also great, thanks